# Compare Two Lists and find similar data

Tags: c#, list

I have following Class available.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public void ProcessData(List<ClassA> clsA , List<ClassB> clsB)
    {
        // what???
    }
}
```

Value in List A :

[image]

Value in List B :

[image]

i want to compare list A with list B. 
i.e: get data from list A whose Data property is same as in B.

With join or contains i can get 4 values, but i should get only 3 values from list A because order is also mendatory, means 3 values in list B must in same order in List A.

So, Id = 6 in list A will not be considered..

Please Help!!!

EDIT :

It should also work with following data in ListA. List B is as above.

[image]

Please refer updated question.

Comment: Why do you have two different classes with the exact same properties?

Comment: It's a scenario. yes, we can do it with single class also..

Comment: @PrinceT what is your expected output with the new sample data?

Comment: @PrinceT I'm guessing that this is a list based (instead of character array based) verions of the longest common substring. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)  This is a hard problem when the data is in an array -- it will be harder in a list.  Is this what you want to do -- or do you want all common sub-strings equivalent.

Comment: Why do you have two different classes if those classes have an identical definition?

Comment: @Hogan It looks like he wants to find all instances of B as a subsequence of A, not the longest common substring.  It appears that if there is no full substring of B in A it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: @Servy - Maybe.  I'm waiting for an answer since what the OP wants really isn't clear and keeps changing.

Comment: @Hogan, I want to find all instances of A which are in same order as in B. i.e: if B has total 10 records and A has total 20 records. Let's say in B i have 5 records which follows the same sequence in A, i should get those 5 records from A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to find subsequences of the second sequence in the first.  The easiest way to do this is to simply go through the entire first sequence taking subsequences of the size of the second sequence and seeing if they match.

```
public static IEnumerable<T1> FindSubsequence<T1, T2>(
    this IList<T1> first,
    IList<T2> second,
    Func<T1, T2, bool> matchPredicate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var subsequence = first.Skip(i).Take(second.Count);
        if (subsequence.Zip(second, matchPredicate).All(x => x))
            return subsequence;
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<T1>();
}
```

Comment: If you are right about what he is looking for this is a good answer, I'd probably optimize to find all instances of the first element of the 2nd sequence and only check those for a full sequence match.

Comment: @Hogan Given the short circuiting that takes place in `All`, that's exactly what happens.  It won't check the items in the sequence beyond the first if the first doesn't match.

Comment: @Hogan Like I said.  There is no point.  That isn't saving any work over what I'm doing.  In fact, it's doing more, because it's checking the first item twice, not once; if you resolved that issue then it'd be doing the same amount of work but just with more code and complexity, needlessly.  Once again, my code *already* stops comparing the sequences after the first non-match, meaning it's comparing each item against the first item until it finds a match, then it keeps checking each item, stopping as soon as there's a non-match.  Oh, and your code doesn't handle an empty second sequence.

Comment: Doesn't your code regenerate subsequence on every iteration -- mine only generates subsequence on the ones that start with the same item.  So if first sequence is size N and second is size M then mine runs at O(N) and yours at O(NM) assuming a non-trival cost of creating subsequence and a trivial cost of calling matchPredicate.  If matchPredication is a lot more expensive than creating the var subsequence then you are right.

Comment: @Hogan Your assumption is wrong.  The cost of creating the subsequence is O(1), not O(M), due to deferred execution.  Creating a LINQ query that you don't execute is essentially free.

Comment: Ok good point, I'm creating the anon object so that cost is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why we can't also compare by value as well? This worked for me:

```
static public void ProcessData(List<ClassA> clsA, List<ClassB> clsB)
    {
        var newlist = (from a in clsA 
                             from b in clsB 
                             where a.data == b.data && a.value == b.value 
                             select a).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: He explains in the question exactly why this isn't an option.

Comment: @Servy Oops totally missed the order there....Both tables he showed ended up with the same order and I kinda rushed that one.....lol

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Hogan suggested, if you need result as list of one of the classes i.e. either ClassA or ClassB, then you need to do something like below:

```
var result = clsA.Zip(clsB, (a, b) => (a.Id == b.Id && a.Data == b.Data) ? a : b as object);
```

Note that, you need to cast the other class as object, since ternary operator does not operate on different types of output.

Here you'll get List of ClassA as output.

Comment: This doesn't work for the second example provided.  You only find the subsequence if it's at the start of the sequence when you need to check the entire sequence.